# General practice on reservation of deployment wallets

Tags: solidity, tokens, contract-deployment, wallets

Is there a consensus (or a generally accepted recommended practice) about reserving a token contact deployer wallet (to avoid deployments on other production contracts, or even development deployments in test nets, for example) ?

The context is : I had a previous project manager who complained about a colleague using the same wallet for transactions other than token creation, even for other production activities. Initially, I felt that creating different wallets for each application (like on the same project, a wallet for a token, a wallet for the app #1, etc) was overmanagement, but I am now wondering if there is a generally accepted standard for this issue.

Comment: Can you be more precise? What do you mean by avoiding deployments on other production contracts?

Comment: Sure! Just included some context.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, as I know, there is no such standard for managing multiple wallets. You are the one that needs to take responsibility over this process e.g. creating a separate wallet for each project you are working on.

Thus, the best practice is the one described by you. Use a different wallet for each different environment to isolate your personal interactions with the blockchain from those of the project.